# UITableView and paginated data from web service

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I have a JSON feed of articles with 10 articles per page. JSON structure is something like this

```
{ 
  "total_entries": 150,
  "next_page": "http://localhost/?page=2",
  "entries": [{"title": "Title 1"}, {"title": "Title 2"}],
  "per_page": 10
  "current_page": 1
}
```

I want to show the titles in `UITableView` and when you scroll down, the app should fetch articles from the next page.
Right now I'm fetching the first 10 articles in viewDidLoad. The pagination logic, if I understand it correctly, should happen in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

What's the best way to structure such an app? Should I store all articles that I get from JSON in memory? Then it can be up to 150 `NSDictionary` objects, all of them are pretty small though. Or should I save articles in sqlite or core data? Are there any examples of dealing with `UITableView` and paginated lists that come from a web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

great example of parsing XML from webservices is SeismicXML from Apple

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SeismicXML/Introduction/Intro.html

and I found another one for you - iPhone JSON Flickr Tutorial

http://iosdevelopertips.com/networking/iphone-json-flickr-tutorial-part-1.html

this is rather old (2009) but hope it helps to figured it out ^)d